# Center content box and have a navigation box left to it

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar on top, horizontally. This navigation bar is centered in the middle of the page and has no fixed width.

Below, I have a content box, which gets a max-width approaching the width of the top navigation, it is also centered.

Now, I want another navigation box at the left side of the content (can be with fixed width, but better not), but the content still to be centered (not a box including both navigation and content).

[problem with center http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4306/problemcenter.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4306/problemcenter.png)

So the code looks like this:

```
<nav id="main-navigation"></nav>
<nav id="sidenav"></nav>
<section id="content"></section>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make a diagram, very unclear.

Comment: You might want to look at http://www.getskeleton.com/, might save you some headaches.  Also, this question has been asked many times before... do some googling first.

Comment: I was googling my head of, but i didnt find anything. And i wont use any frameworks or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VNxsK/6/).

`#sidenav` is positioned absolutely with its parent being `#content`.

Comment: I thought about this, but i think am getting into trouble if the viewport is getting smaller?

Comment: How so? Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VNxsK/7/) with `#sidenav` having a fluid width.

Comment: yah, but if the viewport is getting smaller or equal than the width of the content box, the sidebar is disappearing (to the left).

Comment: You can't have `#content` centered without this happening. You'd have to have `#sidenav` and `#content` inside a wrapper that's centered.

Comment: Ok, i thought there might be a solution.. but ok, so media queries again.. thx.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, I would like to recommend the following:

1. Wrap the elements above with a container.
2. Apply `position:relative` to this new container.
3. Next, apply `position:absolute` to **#sidenav**.
4. Finally, go ahead and position **#sidenav** by applying `right:100%`
   to it.

And there you have it! All you need to do now is style it accordingly.

**[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Rbc/)** for a working example.

Comment: Well, `left:0` forces **#sidenav** to grow in towards the interior of the container (where the content is), whereas `right:100%` allows it to grow outwards away from the interior of the container (which seems like the desired effect here). It also allows the element to be positioned regardless of its own width; width-agnostic.

Comment: `right:100%` puts #sidenav outside of the parent container; not usually good practice to do this.

Comment: Please explain how it's "not usually good practice"? Also, laura wants **#content** and **#main-navigation** to remain centered. Doing it this way allows the OP to keep her centered layout *without* the **#sidenav** nudging it over. It's essentially the same thing as subtracting the width of **#sidenav** and using that value for `left`, but my method is width-agnostic. Laura can change the size at any time and it'll stay put regardless.

Comment: seems to work, but only if i set a width to the container. As i want to keep the possibility to give the navigation bar a width of 100% (but still centered links), a version without a fixed width would be better for me. I thougt about putting the sidebar in the content container then giving it a negative value of left for positioning. but this seems not to be working fluently if the viewport gets smaller. any more ideas? but thanks so far.

Comment: You can take **#main-navigation** out of the container so its size isn't determined by its parent. That's one way. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Rbc/1/)

Comment: yah, but it has the effect, that the box is disappearing if the window is getting to small instead of the content box going below it or resizing first. So I have to work with media queries, i think, to make it fitting and will be using the other method because it is fitting better semantically. thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using media queries? If anything, it's more empowering.

Comment: Nothing wrong, but without is easier to maintain ;) I just like solutions which are fitting for everything, just personal :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for: [fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/jlowgren/pwd4G/)